# Why won't my Java Map compile in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, dictionary, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a Scrabble game using Java in IntelliJ. I decided to use a `Map<Character, Integer>` which will contain each letter tile and its corresponding scoring value. I figured I could use the `ofEntries` shorthand to initialize the values of the Map but each time I try to compile my program I get an error.

```
error: cannot find symbol Map.entry('A',1)  
symbol: method entry(char,int)  
location: interface Map  
26 errors (1 for each Map entry)
```

At first I thought it might have something to do with the Map being of type Character, Integer and the error mentioning `entry(char,int)` but it is my understanding that Java uses autoboxing between primitives and their object wrappers.

```
import java.util.Map;

class Scrabble {
    private final Map<Character, Integer> LETTER_SCORES = Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry('A',1), Map.entry('E',1), Map.entry('I',1), Map.entry('O',1),
            Map.entry('U',1), Map.entry('L',1), Map.entry('N',1), Map.entry('R',1),
            Map.entry('S',1), Map.entry('T',1), Map.entry('D',2), Map.entry('G',2),
            Map.entry('B',3), Map.entry('C',3), Map.entry('M',3), Map.entry('P',3),
            Map.entry('F',4), Map.entry('H',4), Map.entry('V',4), Map.entry('W',4),
            Map.entry('Y',4), Map.entry('K',5), Map.entry('J',8), Map.entry('X',8),
            Map.entry('Q',10), Map.entry('Z',10)
    );

    private String word;
    private int wordScore;

    Scrabble(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure IDE is configured with correct java compiler. Compilation will fail for java < 9

Comment: What Java version? [How to directly initialize a HashMap (in a literal way)?](//stackoverflow.com/a/6802502)

Comment: I think @YogeshBadke is correct. I get the same error with JDK 1.8. With 1.12, I don't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `Map.entry` was only added in Java 9. In 1.8 you'd not have it compiled, unless you use JDK >=9 with source compatibility set to 1.8.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: AFAIK setting Eclipse compliance only changes language level constructs it accepts. It still uses whatever JDK is configured to figure out methods that exist.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications/corrections

Comment: I am running java 1.11.0 openjdk. I believe I have this set correctly in IntelliJ (File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> 11)

Comment: @RussellKnight - Check your classpath. It appears IntelliJ is finding a pre-JDK 1.9 version of `Map`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, it appears I have conflicting versions of java installed on my machine. I'll try cleaning this up and changing the classpath.

Comment: Wonderful it's all working. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please go to *Project Structure | Project | Project SDK* and define here JDK > 9 and Language level > 9. Also go to *Project Structure | Modules* and check that corresponding language level for module is defined here as well. Your code sample should compile without failures with JDK > 9 as was correctly mentioned in comments.

Comment: It is also worth to check Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler and change the Project bytecode version to the desired java version.